# Is there a better way to compare huge dataset supplied by the user to the entries in the database?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, query-optimization

I have 5 million entries in a MySQL database with the following structure

```
id (primary_key), name, phone_number
1, John Doe, 12346789
```

.....

My tool scrapes the internet continuously, grabs the data and captures millions of new data. Now that scraped data is passed to the processDataInChunks function with 10000 entries at once.

I am trying to compare the scraped data to the rows in the database and insert it if it doesn't exists. To implement it I have used sequelize in Node.js and here's the code implementation:

```
// data = chunk of data collected by the scraper
// callback = function to call when new entry is detected
function processDataInChunks(data, callback) {
   data.map(function (entry) { // loop through the data array where entry is nth element of the array
      db.findAll({phone_number: entry.phone_number}) // db variable represents the SQL table
         .then(function (rows) { // call this function with rows as argument when the query is successful
            if (!rows.length > 0) { // if phone number is not in the database
               db.create({ // create entry in the database
                  name: entry.name,
                  phone_number: entry.phone_number
               }).then(function () {
                  callback(entry);
                  console.log(`Found a new phone number: ${entry}`)
               }).catch(err=>console.log(err))

            }
         }).catch(err=>console.log(err))
   })
}
```

While, running the code I'm getting `ConnectionAcquireTimeoutError` error. I am assuming that the error is being encountered because all the connections are being consumed and sequelize doesn't have any more to provide to perform new queries. What is the best and fastest way to perform the operation? Please help.

I have tried using async/await but still it takes ages and I don't think it will ever complete.

Comment: Load the user supplied data into a temp table, then do an insert ... select ... to merge the two tables.

Comment: You may want [upsert](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js~model#static-method-upsert). Create a unique constraint on `phone_number`, then you can upsert your incoming rows without searching for matching rows first.

Comment: I agree w/ the upsert idea. Also sounds like a connection pool issue too... https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/connection-pool/

Comment: Hi everyone, thank you so much for pointing me out in the right direction. However, upsert won't work here because I need to perform a lot of queries and the connection pool issue is going to come up again. I also need to get the unique rows only so I've decided to go with the suggestion of @Shadow because I can compare and fetch all the unique records in a single query. Inserting the data won't be a problem because sequelize offers a bulkCreate method which handles connection pool problem by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be issuing at least two SQL statements per incoming row.  By really batching, you can get 10x speedup.

Use `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`  (aka IODKU or upsert).  It avoids having to do the initial select.  That speedup of 2x.

Batch them in clumps of 1000 -- 10000 might be slightly faster, but may run into other issues.

Are most of the entries unchanged?  Or is everything you get going to be either a new entry or an update?  There may be some extra optimizations if the data tends to be one way versus the other.  (IODKU is happy to handle all 3 cases.)

Does the data provide the `id`?  Is it consistent?  Or is the `name` the actual clue of which row to update?  In this case, what index do you have?  Can ther be two *different* people with the same name?  If so, how would you differentiate their rows?

You could feed the chunks to multiple threads.  This would provide some parallelism.  Stop at about the number of CPU cores.  And do keep the chunk size down at 1000; 10000 is likely to have locking issues, maybe even deadlocks.  And do check for errors.

It is possible to write a single IODKU that handles a thousand rows.  Or you could throw all the data into an temp table and work from there.

If you receive only one row at a time, please spell out the details; an extra step will be needed to collect the data.

Summary --

- 10x for batching statements
- 2x for IODKU
- 5x(?) for parallelism

Total *might* be 100x.  Does that sound better?